# Using Class vs Module for packaging code in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, module, mixins

Let's say I have a bunch of related functions that have no persistent state, say various operations in a string differencing package. I can either define them in a class or module (using `self`) and they can be accessed the exact same way:

```
class Diff
  def self.diff ...
  def self.patch ...
end
```

or

```
module Diff
  def self.diff ...
  def self.patch ...
end
```

I can then do `Diff.patch(...)`. Which is 'better' (or 'correct')?

The main reason I need to group them up is namespace issues, common function names are all used elsewhere.

Edit: Changed example from matrix to diff. Matrix is a terrible example as it *does* have state and everyone started explaining why it's better to write them as methods rather than answer the actual question. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your two examples, you are not actually defining methods in a `Class` or a `Module`; you are defining singleton methods on an object which happens to be a `Class` or a `Module`, but could be just about any object. Here's an example with a `String`:

```
Diff = "Use me to access really cool methods"

def Diff.patch
  # ...
end
```

You can do any of these and that will work, but the best way to group related methods is in a `Module` as normal instance methods (i.e. without `self.`):

```
module Diff
  extend self  # This makes the instance methods available to the Diff module itself
  def diff ... # no self.
  def patch ...
end
```

Now you can:

- use this functionality from within any Class (with `include Diff`) or from any object (with `extend Diff`)
- an example of this use is the `extend self` line which makes it possible to call `Diff.patch`.
- even use these methods in the global namespace

For example, in `irb`:

```
class Foo
  include Diff
end
Foo.new.patch # => calls the patch method
Diff.patch    # => also calls Diff.patch
include Diff  # => now you can call methods directly:
patch         # => also calls the patch method
```

*Note*: the `extend self` will "modify" the `Diff` module object itself but it won't have any effect on inclusions of the module. Same thing happens for a `def self.foo`, the `foo` won't be available to any class including it. In short, only instance methods of `Diff` are imported with an `include` (or an `extend`), not the singleton methods. Only subclassing a class will provide inheritance of both instance and singleton methods.

When you actually want the inclusion of a module to provide both instance methods and singleton methods, it's not completely easy. You have to use the `self.included` hook:

```
module Foo
  def some_instance_method; end

  module ClassMethods
    def some_singleton_method; end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :extend, ClassMethods
  end

  def self.will_not_be_included_in_any_way; end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end
# Bar has now instance methods:
Bar.new.some_instance_method  # => nil
# and singleton methods:
Bar.some_singleton_method   # => nil
```

Comment: Yes you are right I am not using a class or mixin, I just want something akin to Java's package. I will use module then as it seems to be the way cool kids do it. I don't need the mixin capability though.

Comment: Btw, won't "extend self" interfere with inclusion? It should make whatever class you include it in do "extend self" as well, which is most likely not intended.

Comment: @alexloh: It won't. Answer modified.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between modules and classes is that you can not instantiate a module; you can't do `obj = MyModule.new`.  The assumption of your question is that you don't want to instantiate anything, so I recommend just using a module.

Still you should reconsider your approach: rather than using arrays of arrays or whatever you are doing to represent a Matrix, it would be more elegant to make your own class to represent a matrix, or [find a good class that someone else has already written](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html).

Answer (score 2):

Ruby Modules are used to specify behaviour, pieces of related functionality.

Ruby Classes are used to specify both state and behaviour, a singular entity.

There is a maxim in software design that says that code is a liability, so use the less code possible. In the case of Ruby, the difference in code lines is cero. So you can use either way (if you don't need to save state)

If you want to be a purist, then use a Module, since you won't be using the State functionality. But I wouldn't say that using a class is wrong.

As a trivia info: In Ruby a Class is a kind of Module.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html

Comment: @alexloh I changed the answer

Comment: Thanks. I will be using Module since this seems to be what the cool kids do.

Answer (score 1):

The following also works

```
Matrix = Object.new

def Matrix.add ...
def Matrix.equals ...
```

That's because so-called "class methods" are just methods added to a single object, and it doesn't really matter what that object class is.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of form, the Module is more correct. You can still create instances of the class, even if it has only class methods. You can think of a module here as a static class of C# or Java. Classes also always have the instance related methods (`new`, `allocate`, etc.). Use the Module. Class methods usually have something to do with objects (creating them, manipulating them).