# Ruby namespacing with a class vs. module?

Tags: ruby

Consider the Ruby class `Foo::Bar`.

The convention is for the 'Foo' namespace to be a module, but it could just as easily be a class:

```
module Foo; class Bar; end; end
```

Versus:

```
class Foo; class Bar; end; end
```

In the second case, `Bar` is not an inner class of `Foo`, it's just another constant defined on the singleton of `Foo`. The superclass is Object in both cases and they only include the Kernel module. Their ancestor chains are identical.

So, besides operations you could make with `Foo` depending on its class (instantiate if a class, extend/include if a module), does the nature of the namespace have any effect on `Bar`?  Are there compelling reasons to choose one many of name-spacing over another?

The only sort of weird things I see you can do are `Foo::Bar.new.extend Foo` and `Foo.new.class::Bar` respectively.

My own most-common use of a class defined in a class would be a helper struct/class that is meant to be only used internally by the class:

```
class Foo
  Bar = Struct.new(:something) do
    def digest
      puts "eating #{something}"
    end
  end
  def eat(something)
    Bar.new(something).digest
  end
end
```

The closest I found to this discussion is in "[Using Class vs Module for packaging code in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496803/using-class-vs-module-for-packaging-code-in-ruby)".

Comment: Interestingly, I see there was a related issue in Rails using const_missing http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/2740

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most immediate benefit to using modules for namespacing is that you can use `include` to import the namespace, and use the constants declared within it unqualified:

```
module Foo; class Bar; end; end

module Elsewhere
  include Foo
  Bar.new
end
```

Comment: Ok, I can see that as a convincing argument where using a module is *intended* to be mixed in.  But if not intended, like most gems, mixing the gem's top namespace in is liable to cause collisions with existing constants.

Comment: BTW, if I don't get more answers, I'll accept this ( I did upvote it), but I was hoping for something more complete.

Comment: Sure, thanks. The only other reasons I can think of are "convention" and "clarify of intention", neither of which are much more satisfying than that. Class and Module are so close mechanically because Class is actually a subclass of Module that implements instantiation. I've thought before that an actual independent Namespace construct might be nice, but I'm not sure what behavior it would actually add, so I can see why it's all done with Modules now.

Comment: I agree the that it's basically a convention to use modules for namespaces.  I am asking, in part, if the convention is basically an arbitrary decision that you are more likely to need to include/extend a namespace than instantiate it.  But, that possibility aside, they behave and perform exactly the same?

Comment: More or less. See: `Class.instance_methods - Module.instance_methods => [:allocate, :new, :superclass]` and the [source for include](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-include) which explicitly calls `Check_Type(argv[i], T_MODULE);`.

Comment: I feel like there's gotta be some case, from the perspective of Bar, where it is different if it is defined in a module vs. a class but I haven't found any yet.

Comment: In my use case,  Foo has to be a class: I'm writing objects that needs to be instantiated. But I still want to have this extra helper class Bar, and I only need Bar for internal operations of Foo. I've been convinced to use modules as namespaces by the convention rule, and so to *not* nest Bar inside Foo. But the result of that is that in addition to class Foo I have module Foos just so that I can have Foos::Bar. Rethinking this in the context here, I feel like this is actually slightly worse because it adds another name without any good reason.